# What can I include in 3rd-party content?

Tags: dnd-5e, books, publishing, intellectual-property

What WotC 5e D&D content am I and am I not allowed to use in published 3rd-party content? Core books? Books like Xanathar's and Volo's? Unearthed Arcana? How do I avoid plagiarism, copyright infringement, etc?

Right now, I want to provide on my site/blog short campaign settings for dungeon masters to use as starting ideas for their games. If I create enough, I'm considering package them together in a PDF and sell them on something like DriveThruRPG.

Comment: This question is on topic. [We handle advice for people looking to publish on matters of publishing law and copyright.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5565/1204) This is an RPG publishing question, and is materially relevant to our domain. Many of us have to understand these things in order to engage in our day-to-day work, including those of us that do actually publish RPGs. We're also well equipped to understand the licensing specifically involved in D&D 5e.

Comment: I have voted to close this as a duplicate of a previously asked question.  If you have not already downloaded the [SRD/OGL Version 5.1 from the WoTC web site](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf), then you need to do that before you go any further.  [Also read the FAQ](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/systems-reference-document-srd), and then please revise your question if more things are unclear.

Answer (score -3):

Short story you can ONLY use info from the SRD.

Longer story here and with your neighborhood copyright attorney:
http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/systems-reference-document-srd

Comment: How do you explain the use of 5e material beyond the SRD that's allowed in DM's Guild submissions?

Comment: @nitsua60 I think the question is a dupe, and marked it so.

Comment: Unless you choose not to accept that license, in which case there are other options. Check out the question now linked as a duplicate in the question above — its answers are informative!